# Overloading Delete Operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, delete-operator

In my code, i have overloaded the `new` and `delete` operators to get filename and line number. In my code I am using `map` and `stack`. When i do erase a particular value from the map it just call my overloaded `delete` function but I want only explicit `delete` statements to be able to access my function, not others. How can I do that?

Comment: Interesting question. I think you may need to revise your question with more details so that people will be able to understand your situation. For example, explain why you want to overload the delete operator (debug? logging?) and how you are getting the filename and line numbers. Why can't you modify the code to use the delete macros proposed in the answers below? Etc. Having more background helps the more experienced people here to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want your own delete to call your overload, I would not overload the delete operator but instead make a custom method like DeleteMyObject which would call the original delete and then create a macro to call this function and replace all your deletes with this macro.

Like

```
#define DELETE_MY_OBJECT(obj) DeleteMyObject(obj, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

and the method could look like

```
void DeleteMyObject(void* obj, char* file, char* line)
{
    // Log delete
    ...

    delete obj;
}
```

then in your code

```
MyObj* obj = ...
...
DELETE_MY_OBJECT(obj);
```

Comment: i already have a code and cannot change in the code, i can just add macros and invoke function. Thats why i had to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `stack` **are** explicitly calling `delete yourObject` under the hood, for most definitions of "explicit"—that's why your delete operator is getting called. Those deletes are no less legitimate than ones in your code.

How do you get the file name and line number, by the way? Beware that `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` probably won't work. Those will return the file name and line number of the line number they're found on, meaning you'll get the location of your `delete` method, not the location of the *caller*.

To get the behavior you want, both only logging "explicit" deletes and tracking their location, you'll need to replace the deletions you want to log with macro calls. In that case you don't need to override `delete`. For example:

```
#define DELETE(p) \
    do { \
        std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": " << p << std::endl; \
        delete p; \
    }
```

Comment: Because it will always be called from the file where you overload the delete operator. See my response for a way to overcome that.

Comment: yes i know but i have another way to get filename and line number. Problem is not getting the filename but its about how to stop calling delete function. My mean with explicit was not any specific type. for ex: char * ptr = new char[40];                      delete ptr  ---  should call my delete function but suppose i have one map. if i write map.erase() it shouldnot call my delete function.

Comment: For the specific case of map you could create your own allocator that explicitly doesn't call `delete` but I can't fathom why you'd want to do this.